# how to make uv sphere with different colors in in like this

Tags: modeling, python, rendering, animation, scripting

how do you make colours inside the UV sphere? Like red and dark inside it

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssW4d.png]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: It looks like a glass shader ...